# Way of displaying items in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am displaying collection of object as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<class1> collection1 {get;set;}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection1=new ObservableCollection<class1>();
        collection1.Add(new class1());
        collection1.Add(new class1());

        DataContext=this;
    }
}

public class class1
{
    public class1() {;}

    public static implicit operator string(class1 c)
    {
        return "object type of class1";
    }
}

}
```

WPF file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" />
</Window>
```

Normally it gives such a result:

WpfApplication4.class1

WpfApplication4.class1

However I'd like to display it another way, for example result of string operator conversion.

Of course I can add to class1 string element, but I'm interested is there any way to deal with this issue faster and with less code used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no data template is defined for a given type, `ToString()` is called over each object bound, so if you would like to return the string from the code you'd override `ToString()` in `class1` as follows (reusing your implicit conversion operator):

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (string)this;
    }
```

The XAML approach would be to define a data template, declaring how to render `class1` objects. In the following example, it simply contains a `TextBlock` with a fixed text:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:class1}">
            <TextBlock>Class1 object</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" />

</Window>
```

Alternatively, instead of declaring the data template globally inside your window (i.e. in Window.Resources) for all instances of `class1`, you can define it locally for the ListView. You'd remove the `<Window.Resources>` section of the previous code and replace the `ListView` as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>Class1 object</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```